# Http Post is sending request with null body

Tags: c#, .net, angular, asp.net-web-api

I have a .NET API which is as follows

```
public List<long> Compare ([fromBody] String NumberOfDatasets)
```

I am trying to access the API from an angular app. GET requests works fine, but when i try to send a POST request it goes without a body and the API receives a null parameter.

I have checked the API by accessing it from fiddler and it works fine.
Also i have enabled

- CORS
- HttpPost
- HttpOptions

for the api.
Also the headers are getting added properly which i checked through Chrome dev tool. Am i missing anything here ?

My angular app component's TS file is as follows :

```
myFunction()
{
   let httpHeaders = new HttpHeaders({
     'Content-Type' : 'application/json'
   });
   let options = {
     headers: httpHeaders
   };
   return this.httpClient.post(myUrl, "5", options);
}
```

Comment: I don't think "5" is valid application/json content. Did you try setting the request body to `{ "NumberOfDatasets" : "5" }`?

Comment: Yes i tried that too. Also Tried JSON.Stringify({NumberOfDatasets : 5})

Comment: Did you try `JSON.stringify("5")`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Posting a string as body when using the content-type of `application/json` is not acceptable as the 
json will try to parse from an object `{}` or array `[]`. 
To send a single string as the request body change the content type to `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` and adding a equal sign (`=`) infront of the string

Try it this way

```
myFunction()
{
   let httpHeaders = new HttpHeaders({
     'Content-Type' : 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
   });
   let options = {
     headers: httpHeaders
   };
   return this.httpClient.post(myUrl, "=5", options);
}
```

Comment: This Worked. Thank you :)
And sorry for being late to mark it as the answer

Answer (score 1):

`"5"` is not a valid JSON, thus MVC cannot deserialize it and returns null.

Correct way of passing string as JSON is to encapsulate it in quotation marks:

```
"\"5\"" //that's the way you should write it in JS
```

or use

```
JSON.stringify("5")
```

which will give you correct JSON string of any object you'd like to.

Moreover, passing `{ NumberOfDatasets: "5" }` doesn't work, because proper deserialized object for it would have to look like this:

```
public class DatasetsNumber
{
    public string NumberOfDatasets { get; set; }
}
```

which clearly isn't string on its own.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But sadly i have tried that too.
Also as per what i know, the httpClient.post can accept any type of parameter as the body which will be implicitly converted into a JSON object